# Android: Dialog with proportional width

Tags: android, dialog

How can I create a dialog in Android (based on a table-layout) that has width proportional to the screen width (for ex. 60%)? The following code takes all the width of the screen.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TableLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Ok"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/text"
                    android:layout_span="2"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Comment: post a screenshot of how it looks now. normally dialogs don't take up 100% of the width of the screen, if yours is we'll need to see how you are creating and showing it as well.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know it isn't possible but maybe this might work; in your activity try to access your xml layout- TableLayout tl=(TableLayout)findViewById(...) and try to get your devices screen width

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width=display.getWidth();
```

and then set some value based on that width via

```
rl.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width*0.7,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT(or something else) ));
```